# Change python command to subtract value instead of add in MYSQL

Tags: python

Just got one other question for my python plugin.
Here is the code:

```
def cmd_give(self, data, client=None, cmd=None):
    """ 
    ^3<player> <money> - Give someone however much money you want.
    """
    input = self._adminPlugin.parseUserCmd(data)
    if not data:
        client.message('^7 correct syntax is !give <player> <money>')
        return False
    else:
        if  len([x for x in data if x.isspace()]) < 1:
            client.message('^7 correct syntax is !give <player> <money>')
            return False
        else:
            input_data = data.split(' ',1)
            scname = input_data[0]
            ammount = int(input_data[1])
            sclient = self._adminPlugin.findClientPrompt(scname, client)
            if not sclient: return False
            self.earn_money(sclient, ammount)
    return True
```

Now this obviously adds the value given in the command to the user inputting into mysql.
I'm also wanting a command to subtract any value given in the command as well.
So this command above is a give and I also want a take. 
My problem is I don't know what the change is to minus the amount off the value input instead of adding.
Hope someone can help,
Thanks guys.

Comment: Note: I know about the "ammount"

Comment: Can you add a negative amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying the function that does the actual addition, the suggestion by Rob Watts in a comment will work:

```
ammount = -int(input_data[1])
```

You can either create a new function, `cmd_take`, and do that there, or have a more general function (`cmd_transaction`?) that takes an extra argument (eg give) and has the appropriate logic:

```
if not give:
    ammount = -int(input_data[1])
```

In the first case, it would be good practice to extract most of the code to a helper function, to avoid repetition, but if you don't know python and this is just a one time thing, having a `cmd_take` function that is exactly like `command_give`, except for that one line, is the simplest solution.

Comment: Well I figured it would be basically the same but just a different input type value. I wouldn't know how to use operator etc.
I don't really know python btw.

Comment: There's nothing more to using `operator` than what I wrote in my answer. I added an alternative based on a comment.

Comment: Yes ok but how can I implement it into the plugin.
And yes I am pretty stupid on this of course why I came here :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: That depends on the `earn_money` method. My first suggestion was under the assumption that you could change that method, since you don't have here the code to actually add the money. Try changing the line `ammount = int(input_data[1])` to `ammount = -int(input_data[1])`, to see if that works to subtract money from the player. If it does, I can give you a simple solution.